# rails 5 api selection won't render in view/AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, view, controller

I put together an API controller call in Rails 5.1.4 - it renders fine as a controller on its own (render json test call commented out, but used to test):

```
require "json"

class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # make request to API to get data
 response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/inventories")
 #  Parse the stringified JSON into a ruby object
 parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)

# extract relevant data into an instance variable
transformed_results = []

parsed_json["result"].each do |inventory|
  transformed_results.push(
    {
      product_name: product_lookup(inventory["product_id"]),
      store_name: store_lookup(inventory["store_id"]),
      quantity: inventory["quantity"],
    }
  )
end

# render json: transformed_results
@inventories = transformed_results
end
  private

  def store_lookup(store_id)
  response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/stores/#{store_id}")
    parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  return parsed_json["result"]["name"]
end

 def product_lookup(product_id)
 response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/products/#{product_id}")
     parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
 return parsed_json["result"]["name"]
 end
end
```

Here's my call in index.html.erb:

```
<% @inventories.each do |inventory| %>
  <h2><%= inventory["product_name"] %></h2>
  <p>Located at <%= inventory["store_name"] %>, <%= inventory["quantity"] %> units in stock.</p>
<% end %>
```

Which renders the plain text, but not the called values. Should "product name" not be called as a string? I'm still learning, but I purposely grabbed only three pieces of data from the API as a learning tool.

Incidentally, I also tried grabbing my @inventories data through an AJAX call (jquery for JS, but vanilla preference), with similar issues. I think my main issue is how exactly to grab my data through the controller in either case?

Comment: with `product_name: product_lookup(inventory["product_id"])` your hash keys are symbols and not strings. So, in your view try accessing it like `<%= inventory[:product_name] %>`...

Comment: This works! Hooray for simple solutions :)